How to accept or close cookies popup as this popup doesn't have buttons to close/accept/decline?
I have cookies information banner as soon as I open a website and it doesn't has any buttons to close or accept or decline. I must wait for 10 seconds to get off this banner so then I can run my tests.
Any possible way to handle this type of cookies banner?



Try low level element .remove(), ref Element: remove() method
cy.contains('div[role="dialog"]', 'We use cookies to help')
  .then($el => {
    const element = $el[0]
    element.remove()
  })


Thanks, it worked and also we can set display to none. Both solutions worked.
